# Stuck on proof of step 4 on Thm 7.32 on baby Rudin.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

According to baby Rudin's thm 7.32

Then the uniform closure $B$ of $A$ consists of 'all' real continuous functions of $K$.

and Step 4 in proof:

Given a real function $f$, continuous on $K$, and $\epsilon>0$ there exists a function $h\in B$ such that

$$|h(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon\ \ \ (x\in K)$$

"Since $B$ is uniformly closed, this statement is equivalent to the conclusion of the theorem."

I think we can get continuity if above is satisfied, because of following

$$|h(x)-h(t)|\leq |h(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(t)|+|f(t)-h(t)|<3\epsilon,\ \ \ (x,t\in K)$$

$$\because f \ is \ continuous \ on\ K $$
Then why the uniformly closed is relevant with "all"?

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement of part 4 can be through of like this. Given any real continuous function $f$ on $K$, we can find a sequence of $h_{n}\in B$ such that $h_{n}\to f$ uniformly.

Uniformly closed means that for any uniformly convergent sequence $h_{n}\in B$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} h_{h}\in B$. Thus, we conclude via part 4 that for any real contionus function $f$ on $K$, $f\in B$, which is the desired result.

Comment: I think that I have wrong approach to this proof! thank you, your answer.

Comment: However is it clear if we change the front part of theorem 7.32 as "Let $A$ be an algebra of 'all' real continuous functions on a compact set K."?

Comment: Changing it to "all" would defeat the point of the result. The point of 7.32 is that if you take a nice enough set of continuous functions $A$ on $K$, you can find all continuous functions on $K$ via limits of things in $A$.

Comment: Also, to address what you did in your post. You do not use part 4 to show that anything is continuous. in fact, note that just below (61), we get that $h$ is continuous because $h\in B$ and 7.11.

Comment: Thank you your answer, I think I need more time to concern this theorem more seriously.